# соединить nginx через unix-сокет с uwsgi

Tags: nginx, uwsgi

Действовал по мануалам https://gist.github.com/evildmp/3094281 и https://habrahabr.ru/post/226419/.

```
user nginx;
worker_processes auto;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                        '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                        '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile            on;
    tcp_nopush          on;
    tcp_nodelay         on;
    keepalive_timeout   65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;

    include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type        application/octet-stream;

    # Load modular configuration files from the /etc/nginx/conf.d directory.
    # See http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include
    # for more information.
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

    upstream django {
        server unix:///tmp/site.sock;
    }

    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  X.X.X.X;
        charset     utf-8;

        location / {
            uwsgi_pass  django;
            include     /var/www/site/uwsgi_params;
        }
    }
}
```

из-под пользователя запускаю uwsgi:

```
$ uwsgi --socket /tmp/site.sock --chdir /var/www/site --module  site.wsgi --chmod-socket=777

$ ls -l /tmp/site.sock
srwxrwxrwx. 1 user user 0 апр 20 12:23 /tmp/site.sock
```

однако, nginx при попытке обратиться к странице выдаёт 502 и в логе:

> [crit] 15145#0: *3 connect() to unix:///tmp/site.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: X.X.X.X, server: X.X.X.X, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "uwsgi://unix:///tmp/site.sock:", host: "X.X.X.X"

Если пытаюсь слушать не сокет, а порт, то получаю:

> 15230#0: *1 connect() to X.X.X.X:8000 failed (13: Permission denied) while connecting to upstream, client: X.X.X.X, server: X.X.X.X, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "uwsgi://X.X.X.X:8000", host: "X.X.X.X"

В чём может быть дело?

Comment: `unix:///tmp/site.sock` тут действительно должно быть три слеша? судя по документации, хватит и одного

Comment: То же самое "connect() to unix:/tmp/site.sock failed (2: No such file or directory)", если что система centos7.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> server unix:///tmp/site.sock;

см., например, этот ответ: https://serverfault.com/a/464025/292034

короткое изложение:

помещайте *socket* не в `/tmp`, а в `/var/run`.

---

и, да, одного слэша более чем достаточно:

```
server unix:/var/run/something;
```

---

```
uwsgi --socket /var/run/something ...
```